# Efficacy of home radio frequency devices for skin treatment

Tags: dermatology, medical-device, home-medical-equipment

I recently stumbled across a story about a new type of digital monopolar radio frequency device called Efficy that apparently combines several different methods for tightening existing collagen fibres and stimulating new collagen growth in the skin (essentially to diminish the appearance of wrinkles, but also for treating rosacea and acne). I'd never heard about this method before, and considering that the treatment prices were *quite* expensive, I decided to see if it were possible to acquire a similar device for treatment at home.

It seems there are many such RF devices available, ranging from ~£30 to several thousand pounds, but as a consumer it's difficult to know what to look for. Would any of the home-market devices provide comparable results and/or be worthwhile compared to expensive clinic treatments?

### Edit:

Here's [link with details](https://germaine-de-capuccini.co.uk/about/efficy/) about the Efficy device.

Comment: Looks like the kind of thing that would need to be backed up by a lot of studies. Without them, it seems that it won't work.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this device? It's not readily found with a web search and we have to know what you're talking about.

Comment: @CareyGregory No problem - link added. I questioned whether to add a link before, but didn't want to seem like I was pitching a sale...